# swfobject doesn't seem to work when adding id to element with js

Tags: html, click, append, embed, swfobject

I'm using the google hosted swfobject to try and embed some swf files. It works fine when I add the swfobject id to an element in the HTML. However, I've been attempting to set it up in a different way. ...when an element is clicked, a div is appended with the swfobject id. I have been unsuccessful in accomplishing this.

Does anyone know why this could be?
Any help would be appreciated.

*The reason I need to set it up that way is because I don't want the swf to be visible until a certain element is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should call your function embedding the swf file once you click the div element.

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't even think of that.